# How to statically or dynamically select an option in an select ngOption in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options

I watched a video at http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2452-Mixing-Static-And-Dynamic-Data-In-An-AngularJS-Select-Menu.htm and it is almost getting me what I need.  This Pluncker http://plnkr.co/edit/iy8mdpyg40ot8KEaOjz6?p=preview has an example of how I have a couple of select options set up with AngularJS.  I want to be able to set the option of either/both of the select list by changing the model or just a click event would be enough to get me going.

Comment: Please correct Plunker URL...

Comment: Plunker address corrected.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

While `select` element historically restricts your `options` to only have a string value, ngOptions directive allows you to use full-blown objects as `<option>` value.

But one must remember that `ngOptions` will use strict comparison when comparing the objects from the list with the object in pre-selected model.

This means that, when pre-selecting your model, you must set it to exact same instance of the selected object from the iterated list:

<kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/6A3eF2LeeAon0JZWQY3m?p=preview)**</kbd>

```js
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {

  $scope.options1 = [
    {id: 1, label: 'label1', type: 'type1', parentType: 'parentType1'},
    {id: 1, label: 'label2', type: 'type2', parentType: 'parentType1'},
    {id: 1, label: 'label3', type: 'type3', parentType: 'parentType2'},
    {id: 1, label: 'label4', type: 'type4', parentType: 'parentType2'},
    {id: 1, label: 'label5', type: 'type5', parentType: 'parentType3'}
  ];

  $scope.type = "";

  $scope.options2 = [
    {id: 1, label: 'specialLabel1', type: 'label1', parentType: 'parentType1'},
    {id: 1, label: 'specialLabel2', type: 'label1', parentType: 'parentType2'},
    {id: 1, label: 'specialLabel3', type: 'label2', parentType: 'parentType3'},
    {id: 1, label: 'specialLabel4', type: 'label2', parentType: 'parentType4'},
    {id: 1, label: 'specialLabel5', type: 'label3', parentType: 'parentType5'}
  ];

  $scope.get = function(myarray, type) {
    return myarray.filter( function(value, index, arr) { 
      return value.type == type.label 
    });
  }

  $scope.select = function () {
    $scope.type = $scope.options1[2];
  }

});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MainController'>

  <select 
    ng-model="type" 
    ng-options="p as p.label group by p.parentType for p in options1"
  ></select>

  <select 
    data-ng-model="speciality" 
    ng-options="p as p.label group by p.type for p in get(options2, type)"
  >
    <option value="">None</option>
  </select>

    <hr />
    <button ng-click="select()">Set type</button>

</body>
```